# JavaFX button not working

Tags: java, button, javafx

I started writing a simple music player, but when I tested it, I found that the button wasn't working.  I replaced the code in the button's event handler with a simple System.out.println("Got to button");, but it didn't write to the console.

The fxID of the button is playButton.
The @fxml declaration is:

```
@FXML
 private Button playButton;
```

Initialize:

```
 @FXML
 public void initialize() {
    this.bindGuiComponentsToViewModel();
    this.setEventActions();
 }
```

SetEventActions:

```
private void setEventActions() {
    this.playButton.setOnAction(event -> this.handlePlayAction());
}
```

handler:

```
private void handlePlayAction() {
    System.out.println("got to play");
}
```

I haven't been able to find anything through google for the past hour, I've tried making playButton.setDisable(false);, and nothing has worked so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with the code you have posted. Are the `initialize()` and `setEventActions()` methods getting called? It might help to create a [minimal, complete, executable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include it.

Comment: @James_D I think the initialize() method may not be getting called.  Should it be called from the constructor?

Comment: It should be called for you by the FXMLLoader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not testing the regular way (using an implementation of anonymous class) if it works then the button is bound

```
yourButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
@Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
     System.out.println("got to play");
}
});
```

other solutions :
-Try to use Logger
-Try to Debug the code by adding break point in

```
private void handlePlayAction() {
  x  System.out.println("got to play");
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly new to java, I don't fully understand the first test you gave.  As for the second, I moved my syso directly to the setOnAction (this.playButton.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Got to Event Action");  and it still didn't work

Comment: Well i suggest to to use the code i gave you  instead of what you've write, comment these functions; handlePlayAction and setEventActions

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work though.  I'm actually worried that the GuiCodeBehind isn't getting called at all

Comment: you have to give us more informations , where you call these functions

Comment: I assign the fxml file in my main application, then all the code above is in my GuiCodeBehind file, the button is called like `@FXML
    private Button playButton;`